# Element Groups Count

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I make a Notes application using WPF with MVVM.
I want to make a counter for each i
So there is a task list, every task has importance (none, regular and important).
I want to make listbox, that displays a count of tasks of each importances and bind it to view (counter for each importance), but i don`t know how. Something like that -

1. total - 10
2. none - 5
3. regular - 3
4. important - 2

Task Model:

```
public enum TaskStates
    {
        None,
        Regular,
        Important,
    }

    [DataContractAttribute]
    public class Task : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _name;
        private string _desc;

        private TaskStates taskState;
        public SolidColorBrush TaskBG { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public DateTime CreationDate { get; private set; }

        [DataMember]
        public TaskStates TaskState
        {
            get { return taskState; }
            set
            {
                TaskBG ??= new SolidColorBrush();
                switch (value)
                {
                    case TaskStates.None:
                        TaskBG.Color = Color.FromRgb(0, 113, 127);
                        break;
                    case TaskStates.Important:
                        TaskBG.Color = Color.FromRgb(180, 60, 60);
                        break;
                    case TaskStates.Regular:
                        TaskBG.Color = Color.FromRgb(53, 165, 75);
                        break;
                }
                taskState = value;
                
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TaskState));
            }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string Name
        {
            get => _name;
            set
            {
                _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
            }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string Description
        {
            get => _desc;
            set
            {
                _desc = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Description));
            }
        }

        public Task(string name, string desc,DateTime creationDate, TaskStates taskState)
        {
            this._name = name;
            this._desc = desc;
            CreationDate = creationDate;
            TaskState = taskState;
            
        }

        public Task()
        {

        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged ([CallerMemberName]string prop = "") => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
class TaskViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {        
        public Task CurrentTask { get; set; }


        public DateTime CurrentDate { get; set; }
        IDialogService dialogService;
        IFileService fileService;
        private TaskCommand addTask;
        private TaskCommand removeTask;
        private TaskCommand saveCommand;
        private TaskCommand openCommand;
        private TaskCommand clearCommand;

        public ObservableCollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }

        #region Command Properties
        public TaskCommand AddCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return addTask ?? (addTask = new TaskCommand(
                    new Action<object>(obj =>
                    {
                        Tasks.Add((obj as Task) ?? new Task("Header", "smth", CurrentDate, TaskStates.None));
                    })
                ));
            }
        }

        public TaskCommand RemoveCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return removeTask ?? (removeTask = new TaskCommand(
                    new Action<object>(obj =>
                    {
                        if (CurrentTask != null)
                            Tasks.Remove(CurrentTask);

                    }), new Func<object, bool>(obj => Tasks.Count > 0)
                    ));
            }
        }

        public TaskCommand SaveCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return saveCommand ?? (saveCommand = new TaskCommand(
                    new Action<object>(obj =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            if (dialogService.SaveFileDialog() == true)
                            {
                                fileService.Save(Tasks.ToList(), dialogService.FilePath);
                                dialogService.ShowMessage("File Saved");
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            dialogService.ShowMessage(ex.Message);
                        }

                    }),
                    new Func<object, bool>(obj => Tasks.Count > 0)));

            }
        }
        public TaskCommand OpenCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return openCommand ?? (openCommand = new TaskCommand(
                    new Action<object>(obj =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            if (dialogService.OpenFileDialog())
                            {
                                var newTasks = fileService.Open(dialogService.FilePath);
                                if (newTasks.Count > 0)
                                {
                                    Tasks.Clear();
                                    foreach (var item in newTasks)
                                    {
                                        Tasks.Add(item);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            dialogService.ShowMessage(ex.Message);
                        }
                    }
                )));
            }
        }

        public TaskCommand ClearCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return clearCommand ?? (clearCommand = new TaskCommand
                (
                    new Action<object>(obj =>
                    {
                        var res = MessageBox.Show("Are you Sure?", "Caution", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
                        if (res == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
                            Tasks.Clear();

                    }),
                    new Func<object, bool>(obj => Tasks.Count > 0)
               ));
            }
        }
        #endregion
        public TaskViewModel()
        {
            CurrentDate = DateTime.Now;
            fileService = new JsonFileService();
            dialogService = new DefaultDialogService();

            Tasks = new ObservableCollection<Task>()
            {
                new Task("Important", "Test",CurrentDate,TaskStates.Important),
                new Task("Regular", "Test",CurrentDate,TaskStates.None),
            };

        }
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "") => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: I just don`t know how to make this counter of each importance elements. I tried to make with linq but it just doesn`t update.

Comment: @Shadow_Coder can you show how you have tried? The help will be better if we can see what you're doing wrong rather than giving you a solution out of the blue.

Comment: Alright, I made 3 int properties in ViewModel, here is code:

`public int NoneCount
        {
            get => Tasks.Where(i => i.TaskState == TaskStates.None).Select(i => i).Count();
        }`
(code is similar for 3 properties, just changed TaskState to Regular or Important)
then i binded them to textblock in view, but it doesn`t update when i add new task or when i changing some task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `ValueConverter` to accomplish this.

```
public class TaskStateCountConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        => $"{parameter} - {((IEnumerable<Task>)value).Count(task => task.TaskState == (TaskStates)parameter)}";

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

XAML (you said you wanted a `ListBox`):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:TaskStateCountConverter x:Key="TaskStateCountConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListBox>
        <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding Tasks.Count}"/>
        <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding Tasks,
                               Converter={StaticResource TaskStateCountConverter},
                               ConverterParameter={x:Static local:TaskStates.None}}"/>
        <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding Tasks,
                               Converter={StaticResource TaskStateCountConverter},
                               ConverterParameter={x:Static local:TaskStates.Regular}}"/>
        <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding Tasks,
                               Converter={StaticResource TaskStateCountConverter},
                               ConverterParameter={x:Static local:TaskStates.Important}}"/>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class TaskViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // unchanged parts skipped

    public TaskViewModel()
    {
        Tasks.CollectionChanged += OnTasksChanged;
    }

    private void OnTasksChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        => OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Tasks));
```

It was a bit trickier than I first thought because the converted values are not updated without the event handler (`Tasks.Count` is).

And while you're about it, you could also create a `ValueConverter` for your coloring logic.

**Edit**

To update `TaskViewModel` from within `CurrentTask`:

```
public class TaskViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // unchanged parts skipped

    private Task _currentTask;

    public Task CurrentTask
    {
        get => _currentTask;
        set
        {
            if (value != _currentTask)
            {
                if (_currentTask != null)
                {
                    _currentTask.PropertyChanged -= OnCurrentTaskChanged;
                }
                _currentTask = value;
                _currentTask.PropertyChanged += OnCurrentTaskChanged;
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnCurrentTaskChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == nameof(Task.TaskState))
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Tasks));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is awesome! But there is another problem - it doesn`t update if change importance (i binded combobox to CurrentTask.TastState, it changes importance, but counter doesn`t update)

Comment: That's a tricky one. Basically, you have to somehow call `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Tasks))` from the `TaskState` setter. But you're in a different class there. I'll update my answer.